# click event for HTML dynamic button

Tags: asp.net, html, literals

I'm developing a C# ASP.NET application under VS2010.  I want to generate a dynamic table by writing HTML text into a literal, including dynamically inserted buttons on my table.  I know how to create dynamic ASP.NET controls, but I have a small problem with dynamic HTML controls.  I've created an HTML button but I don't know how to give it a server-side click function.

Can I create dynamic ASP.NET controls and insert them in my literal?  How can I get a dynamically created button to trigger a server-side event?

I've used OnServerClick property for defining my server side function but it has no effect, how can I use this value?

Comment: Where is the table data coming from?  Consider redoing your table creation using the [`Repeater control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx), which will give you much more flexibility in generating your table (including having server-side buttons).

Comment: I know there are better ways of performing this action but I must use literal, I can create button this button tag but I don't know how to add a click event for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want post back on your button click, you will have to add `__doPostBack` function on it's `onclick` event, for this you can add a button like

```
StringBuilder dynamicHtml = new StringBuilder();
dynamicHtml.Append("Your Html Code");
dynamicHtml.Append("<input type='button' id='btn1' name='btn1' onclick='__doPostBack(\'btn1\',\'\')' value='Click Here' />");
```

when you click on it, it will post back, and you can check `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` to find who post back the page.

By checking `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` in Page_Load event handler, you can call your any server side method like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var eventTarget = Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();

    if(eventTarget == "btn1")
    {
        CallMethod1();
    }
}


private void CallMethod1()
{
    //Code which you want to run
}
```

Comment: well thanks but how can I define its click function? what would happen after postback? I want to define a click function for this button

Comment: I used this method but my button doesn't make postback

Comment: Are you getting any JS error? make sure, you have a form tag with runat="server" and your page view source contains __doPostBack function definition.